# How to give field name and show on datagridview for XML Tables?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, localization, linq-to-xml

I'm using C#, XML and LINQ for a project. I wonder it how can be give name (like sql ***as***) a column and show on datagridview.

I created XML code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
  <User User_id="1">
    <User_Code>code 1</User_Code>
    <User_Name>user 1</User_Name>
    <User_PW>11</User_PW>
  </User>
  <User User_id="2">
    <User_Code>code 2</User_Code>
    <User_Name>user 2</User_Name>
    <User_PW>22</User_PW>
  </User>
</Users>
```

If this xml load in dataset and use for datagridview datasource its show columns names like this User_Code, User_Name... But i dont want this. I want to be show column names like (or what i want)
Code, Name, Pw.. Also, i can to try use this for localization too.

I had searched on google but can't find i want.

How i can this?
I hope I explained well.
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Is something preventing you from changing the column headers text in the grid?

Comment: Nothing but i want to make localization. I can change column header in xml file like i want but i dont want this. I just wonder this can be do?

Comment: I looking for change the column headers text in the grid but this way needs some extra code. İf i can i don't want to write code for this.

Comment: I am not sure how you could do this without writing some extra code either in the query or manually changing the column header. How is the code reading the xml data? And what is the data stored in? How is the grid filled with the data?

Comment: My reading xml data is above. 
How i showing data in datagridview codes its under.
`DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
 dataSet.ReadXml(xml_file_path);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
`

Comment: Given the way your code is filling the grid, I do not see how you can change the column headers without either altering the xml, or changing the column header in the data set’s data table or changing the column header in the gird and all those options require writing some extra code. Good Luck.

Comment: I created the XML file above. If we can fix this by making a few changes to the XML, I'll accept it.
I want to provide this with the changes to be made on the XML that I want.
As I said before, we use AS keyword when writing SQL query. Can it be done with something like an attribute or property etc. using a similar expression while preparing the XML?